# How can I fix or replace the fan of a Sapphire ATI Radeon 6770 graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card, fan, amd-radeon

In the last weeks I've noticed the fan of my Sapphire ATI Radeon 6770 graphics card is getting noisier and noisier. So I've tried to get the fan out, peel the sticker below and add a small amount of 3-in-1 oil to the inside of the fan. But it doesn't seem to help much as the noise persists, albeit a little less loud.

For reference, this my card model:
http://www.sapphiretech.com/presentation/product/product_index.aspx?pid=1190&lid=1

Is there anything else I can do to fix it? Is there a replacement fan for this card I can buy somewhere? (And where?). If I can get a new fan, is there a video/website somewhere that shows how can I change it?

Comment: I won't post an answer to this question. I did a google search on `aftermarket ATI Radeon 6770 fan` and found enough results to come to a conclusion. This is possible but requires some technical skill. http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspxItem=N82E16835186053&nm_mc=OTC-pr1c3grabb3r&cm_mmc=OTC-pr1c3grabb3r-_-VGA+Cooling-_-ARCTIC+COOLING-_-35186053 if the card is under warranty I would go that route.  http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/353780-33-radeon-hd6700-broken-help

Comment: You're right that it might be somewhat difficult to change the fan. You just need to get 3 screws out to remove the fan, BUT the cable which connects it to the card goes through the heatsink, so it might be necessary to remove the entire heatsink in order to unplug the old fan and plug a new fan, and I'm not sure how to disassemble that.

Comment: You seem to have enough technical knowledge in order to do so.  You might be able to get a general idea from YouTube videos.

Comment: I'm sure you're aware of this, but I'll mention it anyways; any modification you do will void your warranty!  That wouldn't stop me from tinkering around, but it's worth considering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answer said, aftermarket is an option.  However, I've found that if you just call the manufacturer and describe the issue, they are usually pretty cool about it and will send you a replacement part.  I once got a free replacement CPU fan from CoolerMaster because my fan was getting noisy and I didn't want to take the trouble to replace the entire heat sink and fan.  I didn't even ask for it for free, since it was like 8+ years old, but they just sent it to me for free anyways.

I don't know if ATI is as cool as CoolerMaster (no pun intended) but it's worth a try.

I also once got a whole free set of guitar machine heads from Gibson for free because one of mine broke, and that's on a guitar that was 15+ years old, and again I didn't even ask for it for free, I asked if I could buy the replacement parts.

Each company is different of course, but you'll find alot of them don't mind sending cheap replacement parts out.

Answer (score 2):

Zalman brand is usually pretty good, I've used aftermarket coolers before when I got really crappy ones.  Zalman ones can be found on newegg.com and amazon.com.

Just look up what is compatible via their site / item specs. Usually a few screw holes with a bunch of springs, clean off glue/TIM material off core etc;

**Select Cooling > VGA > AMD:**
http://www.zalman.co.kr/global/product/CategorySecond_Pic.php?categoryname=Cooling&categorySecond=